# Multitenancy: Hibernate with MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, multi-tenant

Multi-Tenant Data Architecture

1. Separate Databases : Supported by Hibernate 4.0.
2. Shared Database, Separate Schemas : Supported by Hibernate 4.0.
3. Shared Database, Shared Schema : Planned for Hibernate 5.0 (DISCRIMINATOR).

However, (unlike Oracle or PostGre)  **MySQL doesn’t seem to have concept of schemas?**, and so if I am using Hibernate + MySQL to achieve multitenancy, is it true that the **only choice I am left over with is Separate Database?**

Comment: Hey there, have you found any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think so. You can create multiple schemas in a single data base in mysql.
So you can go with multiple schemas

Answer (score 0):

You Can use : The Hibernate 4.0 ConnectionProvider
for the same you could switch over the appropriate tenant databases on a data base call when your session is trying to make a Connection to a datasource.

Please check with MultiTenantConnectionIdentifier and MultiTenantConnectionProvider availabled in Hibernate 4.0

For more help you can contact at : sonisatyam92@gmail.com